# Treeset and internal classes‽ How could we get the two indexes of the elements in an array which sum up to a target value‽

Tags: java, arrays, sum, treeset, floor

I have been solving this programming exercise: [Two Sum](https://www.codewars.com/kata/two-sum/java), the statement is:

> Write a function that takes an array of numbers (integers for the
>   tests) and a target number. It should find two different items in the
>   array that, when added together, give the target value. The indices of
>   these items should then be returned in a tuple like so: (index1,
>   index2).
>
> For the purposes of this kata, some tests may have multiple answers;
>   any valid solutions will be accepted.
>
> The input will always be valid (numbers will be an array of length 2
>   or greater, and all of the items will be numbers; target will always
>   be the sum of two different items from that array).
>
> Based on: http://oj.leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/
>
> twoSum [1, 2, 3] 4 === (0, 2)

After doing it by mysef I reviewed other people's answers, and I found a very interesting solution, because of it uses internal classes and a treeset. I would like to fully understand it.

First I will post it and then I will focus on the lines I do not fully understand yet. [Here is the source of the following answer, where you can see the solution posted by the user random76.](https://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/5b1a4703d1925de6ee000fd9/groups/5dc49a1e83a99000011f87c8)

```
import java.util.*;
public class Solution
{
    public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target)
    {
        class Solver {
            final int target;
            final TreeSet<NumberHolder> tree;
            class NumberHolder {
                final int index;
                final int value;
                NumberHolder(int index, int value) {
                    this.index = index;
                    this.value = value;
                }
                int getIndex() {
                    return index;
                }
                int getValue() {
                    return value;
                }
            }
            Solver(int[] numbers, int target) {
                this.target = target;
                this.tree = new TreeSet<NumberHolder>((a, b) -> a.getValue() - b.getValue());
                for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                    tree.add(new NumberHolder(i, numbers[i]));
                }
            }
            int[] solve() {
                NumberHolder fNumber = null;
                NumberHolder sNumber = null;
                Iterator<NumberHolder> it = tree.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()) {
                    fNumber = it.next();
                    sNumber = tree.floor(new NumberHolder(0, target - fNumber.getValue()));
                    if (fNumber.getValue() + sNumber.getValue() == target) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return new int[]{fNumber.getIndex(), sNumber.getIndex()};
            }
        }
        Solver solver = new Solver(numbers, target);
        return solver.solve(); // Do your magic!
    }
}
```

My doubts are:

1) What is the execution flow?

2) Why do we need this line:

```
this.tree = new TreeSet<NumberHolder>((a, b) -> a.getValue() - b.getValue());
```

I understand that we are defining a comparator for our new treeset, but what is its purpose?

3) What is the aim of applying the floor operation on the three?

```
sNumber = tree.floor(new NumberHolder(0, target - fNumber.getValue()));
```

I have read that treeset.floor() gives us the greatest element which value is less than the one given to the floor() method.

I have also read:

[Treeset](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-in-java-with-examples/)
[Treeset floor method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/treeset-floor-method-in-java-with-examples/)

Comment: That's a [*local* class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html).

Comment: "1) What is the execution flow?" What do you mean?

Comment: "2) Why do we need this line:" because either `NumberHolder` doesn't directly implement `Comparable`, or it does but you don't want to use its natural order.